# Print row that causes LangDetectException

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, nlp, language-detection

I have trouble doing a language detection.
The code below raises an Exception Error.

```
from langdetect import detect
for row in df['Comments']:
    text = str(row)
    language_code = detect(text)
    sentence = [all_languages_codes.get(language_code)]
    df['Language']=sentence[0]
```

Error Message:

```
    148         ngrams = self._extract_ngrams()
    149         if not ngrams:
--> 150             raise LangDetectException(ErrorCode.CantDetectError, 'No features in text.')
    151 
    152         self.langprob = [0.0] * len(self.langlist)

LangDetectException: No features in text.
```

How to print-out the row that causes the `LangDetectException`?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your Contents string is empty:

```
detect("")
LangDetectException: No features in text.
```

You can launch a debugger or interactive shell to know for sure, wrapping this in a try/except block and launching a debugger when an exception is raised:

```
from langdetect import detect
for row in df['Comments']:
    try:
        text = str(row)
        language_code = detect(text)
        sentence = [all_languages_codes.get(language_code)]
        df['Language']=sentence[0]
    except Exception:
        import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
```